# How to use bootstrap typeahead with asp.net asmx?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asmx

Before i used succesfully my asmx to return list of cities to jquery ui autocomplete plugin. Now I switched to use bootstrap 3.0 so I changed to typeahead 0.9.3 as well and stuсked with this plugin.
Here is js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tbDestination').keyup(function (event) {
        $("input.typeahead").typeahead({
            source: function (typeahead, query) {
                $.get("http://booking.ilvestour.co.th/citysearch.asmx/SearchCity", { text: typeahead },
                function (data) {
                    return query(data.d);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And asmx code as well:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class citysearch
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function SearchCity(ByVal query As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("hotelbedsConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LocalizedDestination.DestinationRusName + '(' + LocalizedDestination.HBDestinationCode + ')' + ', ' + LocalizedCountryName.RusCountryName As Name FROM LocalizedDestination " & _
                          "INNER JOIN LocalizedCountryName On LocalizedDestination.HBCountryCode = LocalizedCountryName.HBCountryCode " & _
                          "WHERE LocalizedDestination.DestinationRusName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", query)
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim CountryNames As New List(Of String)()
        While sdr.Read
            CountryNames.Add(sdr("Name").ToString)
        End While
        conn.Close()
        Return CountryNames
    End Function
End Class
```

Regarding js. In firebug I can see that at string number three (source: function (typeahead, query) {) it just stop to run and then no any errors message or whatever.
I do not have any idea how to fix it. Please advise.

P.S. Something else that I'm doubt about is - $('#tbDestination').keyup(function (event) because all examples are without that event. But if I'm using without that there just no action I can see in Firebug.

***Update.***
I slightly changed js and asmx code as follow:

```
$(function () {
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'Names',
        remote: {
            url: 'http://booking.ilvestour.co.th/citysearch.asmx/SearchCity?q=%QUERY',
            filter: function (response) {
                return response;
            }
        },
        limit: 10
    });
})
```

and

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function SearchCity()
    Dim city = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("q")
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("hotelbedsConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LocalizedDestination.DestinationRusName + '(' + LocalizedDestination.HBDestinationCode + ')' + ', ' + LocalizedCountryName.RusCountryName As Name FROM LocalizedDestination " & _
                      "INNER JOIN LocalizedCountryName On LocalizedDestination.HBCountryCode = LocalizedCountryName.HBCountryCode " & _
                      "WHERE LocalizedDestination.DestinationRusName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", city)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim CountryNames As New List(Of String)()
    While sdr.Read
        CountryNames.Add(sdr("Name").ToString)
    End While
    conn.Close()
    Dim s As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim json = s.Serialize(CountryNames)
    Return json
End Function
```

Now I believe sure there is correct answer from web service. But I'm stil confused. According to documentation "name" is dataset name, but what is this dataset name here?

Comment: You have a ScriptService without ScriptMethod, the code parameter is named `query` while you pass `text`, and I am wondering if you have the correct http-method (post?) and http-headers (content-type: form/x-www-form-urlencoded). Does Firebug show any http-request being issued? Does your server respond with correct data, or an error message?

Comment: Server respond with correct data, I'm sure, as well as http headers or whatever else regarding server. But I confused about JS part and really do not have idea how to set this plugin.

Comment: Well, seemed like service return xml instead of json.

Comment: Webservices/methods work with soap, you probably want to add the ScriptMethod attribute combined with the correct http headers in the ajax request. And you need to fix your parameter name (query vs text).